# Exclude a usercontrol from being compiled?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to created a class library which contains a custom style for all of my applications I have created (so I have just to import the dll and all the styles are applied). For design purposes I want to have a usercontrol inside my "Theme" project (so I have a visual reprentation of all of my designed controls). But at the end this usercontrol should not compiled and packaged into the dll.

I have already tried to set the build action to *none* but than it cannot find the method (`InitializeComponent()`) which is inside the compiled g.i.cs file (obvious).

But how I can prevent that ?

So basically my project looks like this:

**MyTheme**

- MyThemePreview.xaml <- usercontrol where each widget is defined once
     (Exluded)
- MyTheme.xaml <- merged dictionary with all styles from *Styles*
- Styles

  - Style_Button.xaml
  - Style_TabControl.xaml
  - ...

Comment: Have you also set the `Build Action` of MyThemePreview **.cs** (= code behind) to _None_?

Comment: Have you thought about compiling your code manually using xamlc.exe?

Comment: @Slyvain Omg ... Thank you that fixed my problem. Totally have forgotten that. Maybe you can post a answer. So I can accept it.

Comment: My pleasure, just posted the answer plus extra info just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also set the `Build Action` of the code behind file MyThemePreview **.cs** to *None* as well.

In case you wish to compile this file again, you should set the `Build Action` of `MyThemePreview.xaml` to *Page* and `MyThemePreview.cs` to *Compile*.

Answer (score 1):

- Set `BuildAction` to None, as you were doing
- In `MyThemePreview.xaml.cs` use directive `#if NONEXISTENT_CONSTANT .... #endif` - the code between `#if` and `#endif` wont be compiled if there is no `#define NONEXISTENT_CONSTANT`, and designer will still work. If you want to use the code, just define that constant.
- ... or, if you're never creating MyThemePreview object anway, just get rid of all the code in `MyThemePreview.xaml.cs`. The designer will still work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.100).aspx